# wxPython: Second Row in FlexGridSizer not visible on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Yet another wxPython GUI odyssey and again I seem to be stuck with the problem exposed by the minimal working examplyou can find below:

On macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (wxPython version: 4.0.0b2) I can see the second row ("Text2_fixed Text2_grow") in the FlexGridSizer as soon as I use sizer.SetSizeHints(static_box1):
[display on macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTteR.jpg)

On Ubuntu 16.04 (wxPython version: 4.0.0a2) I cannot see the second row ("Text2_fixed Text2_grow"):
[display on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLbwc.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to make the second row visible on both environments?

Here's the minimal working example:

```
    import wx.lib.inspection

    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title="Top Level Frame", name="Top Level Frame", size=(400, 200))

    box_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    static_box1 = wx.StaticBox(frame, label='Static Box 1', name='Static Box 1', style=0)
    static_box1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 0, 0, 255))
    static_box2 = wx.StaticBox(frame, label='Static Box 2', name='Static Box 2', style=0)
    static_box2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 255, 0, 255))

    box_sizer.Add(static_box1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
    box_sizer.Add(static_box2, flag=wx.EXPAND)

    flex_grid_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(2, 2, 0, 0)
    flex_grid_sizer.AddGrowableCol(1)

    flex_grid_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(static_box1, label='Text1_fixed', name='Text1_fixed', style=0),
                        flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, border=0)
    flex_grid_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(static_box1, label='Text1_grow', name='Text1_grow', style=0),
                        flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, border=0)
    flex_grid_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(static_box1, label='Text2_fixed', name='Text2_fixed', style=0),
                        flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, border=0)
    flex_grid_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(static_box1, label='Text2_grow', name='Text2_grow', style=0),
                        flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.ALL, border=0)

    #SetSizeHints fixes the problem on macOS, but not on Ubuntu
    flex_grid_sizer.SetSizeHints(static_box1)
    static_box1.SetSizer(flex_grid_sizer)
    frame.SetSizer(box_sizer)
    frame.Center()
    frame.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating the frame with a a fixed size then there may not be another `EVT_SIZE` event after the widgets and sizers have been created. Since the default `EVT_SIZE` handler is where the sizer is triggered to do its layout, then that means there will not be an initial layout of the widgets. They will just be left at their default sizes and locations.

An easy workaround will take care of this problem for you. Simply add a call to `frame.SendSizeEvent` after everything has been created and set, to get an extra event so the sizers will be able to do their layout.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestion. It unfortunately didn't fix the problem on Ubuntu, on MacOS this had the effect that I could  remove the flex_grid_sizer.SetSizeHInts() call. Any alternative ideas/approaches from Mr.WxPython? Many thanks!

Comment: It works for me. You may have some luck with slightly delaying the call to `SendSizeEvent` by using `wx.CallAfter(frame.SendSizeEvent)`. You should also try using a version newer than 4.0.0a2.

Comment: Thanks, will try with upgrading!